# How to move forward or any movement which has surface deform modifier

Tags: modifiers, path

I have actually modeled a fish in blender and I had made surface deform modifier on the fish with the help of a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJLIaNhoSSs).

I wanted your help in moving the fish forward or in circular motion but since I added deform modifier it is becoming difficult.

Therefore I humbly request you if you could help in getting the required objective.

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: What is becoming difficult, precisely?

Comment: Just have to parent nearly all to another object.

Comment: The difficulty is random motion of the body because of adding modifier..is there any way i can share my blender file in this forum so that you get an idea of what i am trying to convey..?

Comment: Yes use this site, then paste the resulting link in your question: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The following is the link generated : <img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=56bBWZ0L" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/56bBWZ0L/)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the idea is to take what can be "the main" object to drive all the other ones. If we take the force field and make it parent of the plane (flag like) then the force field will be the parent for all:

Select the flag plane then <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the force field and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> then choose 'Object'.

Now add a curve, make the force field follow a path, adding this constraint:

[image]

The minus X is due to the force field orientation (rotated).

And...

[image]

To change the speed, select the curve and change *"Frames*" (the greater the slower):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out...i want to reduce the speed in which fish is moving so..how do i go about?

Comment: is there any way i can upvote or like you in this forum..?

Comment: Sure just on the left of the questions or answers, up arrow to upvote and down arrow to downvote. I'll give a look about the speed..

Comment: thak you so much for helping me out..